# Uploads from YouTube API are set to Private(locked) despite of completing all the process'

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Recently I have created a project that uploads video to YouTube (Kinda Automation).
But all my uploads through the API are set to private and locked by YouTube despite of me completing all the required process below

- Have completed completed a full audit and this was the reply from YouTube
  [image: (Mail Reply For Audit)]
- Made the app public in console [image: (Published)]
- I Didn't submit the app for verification as the site said **Verification not required**
  [image: (Verification status on screen)]

Despite all these all my uploads remains in private and locked
Kindly Help..!

Comment: I'd recommend to address this issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @stvar Yeah I have made this into google issue tracker but no response from them yet.